# Math.ceil for positive value greater than zero?

Tags: java, ceil

The following code is giving me a wrong answer and I can't understand why.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 15;
        
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(x/y));
```

Result:

```
0
```

I was expecting a 1 as the answer.

Comment: You're dividing two integers, so you get integer division. 10/15 -> 0

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Math.ceil function you passed x / y and the answer of x / y in your case is gonna be 0 cause x and y are both integers and in Java, dividing two integers is going to give an integer result, thus 10 / 15 = 0 without taking the decimal digits.
You can try defining x or y as double. Then you will get 10 / 15 = 0.666... and the ceil will return a 1.

Comment: Please do not add answers to duplicate questions.